# What happens if I convert the .svn directory from ASCII to UTF-8?

Tags: java, svn, utf-8

I am converting my Java project from ASCII to UTF8. I am wondering if I can just simply convert all files to UTF8, or should I exclude some files such as the .svn directories?

Answer (score 3):

If you convert it to UTF-8 **without BOM**, the encoding is identical and it won't make any difference.